# How can a webpage redirect to a new page while clearing "back" history, how to prevent it

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, back-button, browser-history

I've seen webpages that redirect to other pages, and after the new page is loaded, the address bar shows the new URL, but the browser "Back" button is not able to return back to the previous (original) webpage.

I'm talking about a site like "today.com" and other websites that do similar things.

For example, I:

1. start Firefox and open a new tab in a new window (no back history).
2. visit most any article on "today.com" (by clicking a bookmark or pasting a URL into the address bar) such as this webpage: http://www.today.com/video/prince-s-paisley-park-al-roker-gets-first-look-inside-untouched-museum-779588675703 (at least most any page in "/video/" path).
3. watch the video, perhaps pause the video and read the article.

up to this point, everything is as expected. The URL of the bookmark (or the pasted URL) remains shown in the address bar.

After some time I either:

1. resume watching the video to its end, where the webpage automatically loads (redirects) a new "random" article/webpage (well probably not "random" from the site's point of view, but for me, I couldn't tell it from any randomly selected page).
2. or I click a link on the page to a different article on the site.

At this point, the URL of the new page is shown in the address bar and the new page is loaded.

What's troublesome, is that the URL of the original page that I visited (by clicking the bookmark or pasting the URL into the address bar), is (somehow) removed from the browser "Back" history, and replaced with the URL of the new page. Since I opened the page from a new tab, the  "Back" button is not active (not "clickable").

I can repeat this any number of times by letting the video play through and let the next page load automatically, or click another link on the page. The "Back" button is not able to return to any of the previously visited pages.

To be clear, this behavior is not exclusive to the specific webpage I provided the example link for. It happens on many pages but not every page on today.com. And, I've seen similar behavior on other websites.

My question is:

1. How do they do this?
2. More importantly, how can I prevent it?

I was thinking along the lines of using "Greasemonkey" to modify the page to prevent it from doing whatever it does to remove the URLs from the browser back history.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: They are bad people, see [Stealing the users back button with the History API](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/stealing-history-api).